# Pass data to component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-component

I'm using VueJS and I need to pass Firebase Authentication user data (JSON) from the component **App.vue** to another component called **Details.vue** to display the name of that logged in user.

*App.vue:*

```
export default {
    name: 'app',
    beforeCreate: function () {
      Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          this.user = user
// user is logged in now -> pass data to App.vue component here
[...]
```

What is a good way to do this? 
(I'm new to VueJS and tried a couple of suggested answers like using "ref" `<add ref="details"></add>` - unfortunately none of them worked for me)

Comment: would be helpful if you specify how and what exactly doesn't for you. The first thing to try if it's child component is to use `props` property for the component you going to pass data to. More at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props. If it's not describe your problem in more details

Comment: If your project is large enough I recommend checking out [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html). It can act as your store and manage your user state so you don't not need to pass it along to every component using props. Once you have your userState stored you can quickly retrieve that value using getters. You can also store other information pertaining the user in the store to quickly retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long-run solution is Vuex.

If the user is the only global property you want to have, you can create a data property at the root and access from any component using `this.$root.propName`.

Example:

```
// probably main.js file
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {user: null}, // added this
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

App.js:

```
export default {
    name: 'app',
    beforeCreate: function () {
      Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          this.$root.user = user; // set to this.$root.user instead of this.user
```

In any other component:

```
export default {
    name: 'something',
    methods: {
      printUser() { console.log(this.$root.user); }
    },
    // ...
```

That's a quick solution. Don't abuse the `$root` data. Having `user` is like having a global variable. The more code uses it, the harder it becomes to debug. Vuex handles that by having all changes concentrated inside mutations. In summary: if you find yourself needing more `$root` properties, go straight to Vuex.

Comment: Thank you very much, it finally works. `Don't abuse the $root data. Having user is like having a global variable. The more code uses it, the harder it becomes to debug` Like if I change the value of **user** from multiple components or what makes it harder exactly?

Comment: Not just changing `user`. I mean if you add many other variables there. Then many other places will probably be changing those variables simultaneously, possibly asynchronously. At this point, say you want to debug when a variable is being changed, there's no one specific point where you would add a breakpoint, for instance. Anyway, one variable is OK. Just keep Vuex in mind if you find yourself using this `$root` too much.